# How can I search for strings with characters not on the keyboard (non-english)?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, string-matching

I have a search form that I want my users to be able to enter English character equivalents for non-English characters.

For example.
To find Ælfred, the user could search for "Ælfred" or "AElfred".
the search should also be case insensitive so "aelfred" would work.
I also have it searching so that, by default, it matches the beginning of the string so a search of "Æ" or "AE" or even "A" would contain Ælfred in the results.

Other conversions such as ê -> e, å -> a, would need to be accounted for.

I am using ASP.NET with a SQL backend.  Are there any standard libraries that help out with this sort of search?

Comment: @DMan - I guess people should answer more of my questions.

Comment: @cinqoTimo  I am looking for a library or SQL function that would do the Unicode translation of those characters to ones that are type-able on an English keyboard.  Not sure what your suggestion does for me.

Comment: SQL Server's built in full text search can do accent-insensitive searches, but I'm not sure about diphthongs like that. (I assume you're using MSSQL since this is ASP.NET)

Comment: @Jeff- Of your 41 questions, only 3 are unanswered. Not 33%.

Comment: @Ian thats more of a decent answer than a comment.

Comment: @Dman i didn't mean submit an answer, i meant provide an answer i can use.

Comment: @Jeff- that's what bounties are for...

Comment: @Jeff Martin - Be more specific - you said that you were using a SQL back-end, not that you were looking for a SQL library. You are also using ASP.NET which means you could do the comparisons in code using C# and some .NET unicode classes. Your poor question asking and argumentative responses are probably why you're not getting answers to your questions. Try providing a little context, and being nice! :)

Comment: @cinqoTimo  I am currently appending a '%' to the search query and submitting it to MS-SQL.  If there is an easy way to use something built in to SQL or into .NET then I am interested in using it.  Can you give me a lead on the .NET unicode classes you are talking about?

Comment: @Dman but then how would I help someone get a Necromancer badge?  I'm not interested in giving up my rep for most of those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always there is a English character equivalent to a non-English character, but can try to store a **Normalized** string in a different field using [string.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) and comparing to that.

MS SQL fields and full text search catalogs can be accent-insensitive and case-insensitive, so you got the other cases covered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I hadn't considered doing a 2nd field - I may add that in.